# Print array with for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I want to print this array to all indexes upto 21, but in this code this is printing only to array length, what i should i do the print whole array in **for loop**?

```
<?php
$array=array(0=>"hello",
             1=>"world", 
             2=>"this", 
             3=>"is", 
             4=>"an", 
             20=>"array",
             21=>"code" );

$length=count($array);

for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
         echo "$i=>".$array[$i]; 
         echo "<br />";

      }
?>
```

Comment: why not do `$i<21` ? and update your output to check if the value exists?

Comment: Change this `for($i=1;$i<=$length;$i++){` to `for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){`

Comment: It should be `$i < $length`, not `$i <= $length`.

Comment: then every time insert an element i will have to change the length, that's the problem.

Comment: and $i should be initialized to 0, not 1

Comment: you can use $i < sizeof($array) instead of $length, then the array can be variable size

Comment: @user2113060 if you're adding values to your array in your loop, you can try `for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){`

Comment: I am correcting them.

Comment: i have already defined as $length= count($array).

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){` When you do it this way, the array size will be recalculated before each iteration, this is useful if you add values to the end of the array ...

Comment: @user2113060 i now understand what you mean, when you mentioned your array i thought the keys are 1,2,3,4,5 ... 20, 21. But that's not the case ... So why don't you use foreach loop ?

Comment: yeah that's right Hamza, but it won't solve my problem.

Comment: @user2113060 What's the problem then ?

Comment: problem is it will run to array length, and won't print 20, or 21 indexes.

Comment: I am seriously curious; why can't a foreach loop be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your difficulty is the way you're defining your array:

```
$array=array(0=>"hello",
             1=>"world", 
             2=>"this", 
             3=>"is", 
             4=>"an", 
             20=>"array",
             21=>"code" );
```

Arrays in php are really hashmaps; when you call index `5` on the above array, it is undefined. No index item up to 20 will be defined, and these will Notice out:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:  5
```

Because you're using array length as your iterating variable, and calling exactly that variable, you will never get positions 20 and 21 in your code.

This is what your array looks like to the computer:

```
0 => "hello"
1 => "world"
2 => "this"
3 => "is"
4 => "an"
5 => NULL
6 => NULL
7 => NULL
... //elided for succinctness 
19 => NULL
20 => "array"
21 => "code"
```

When you call `$array[7]` it can't return anything. When you call `$array[20]` it will return "array".

What you really want is a foreach loop:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    //key will be one of { 0..4, 20..21}
    echo "$key is $value\n";
}
```

Resulting in:

```
$ php test.php 
0 is hello
1 is world
2 is this
3 is is
4 is an
20 is array
21 is code
```

If you must use a for loop:

```
$key_array = array_keys($array);
for($i=0;$i<count($key_array);$i++){
   $key = $key_array[$i];
   echo "$key => ".$array[$key]."\n";
}
```

Note this is not a clean solution.

Comment: I have asked particularly to use for loop.

Comment: Editted for an explicit for loop.

Comment: thanx, Nathaniel that will do it.

Comment: @NathanielFord +1 for the array_keys() solution, that slipped of my thought !

Answer (score 2):

Solution with a for loop:

```
$array=array(0=>"hello",
             1=>"world", 
             2=>"this", 
             3=>"is", 
             4=>"an", 
             20=>"array",
             21=>"code" );

$max = max(array_flip($array)); // What if max array key is 10^5 ?
for($i=0;$i<=$max;$i++){
    if(isset($array[$i])){
        echo "$i=>".$array[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the poster here has a very salient point if your array is quite large; the performance impact could be meaningful. This solution checks every possible key between 0 and... whatever. Please look into where in a hash map the letter 'a' goes, for instance.

Comment: @NathanielFord Yes you're absolutely right, but it's the SO's wish to do it this way :p

Comment: There are cleaner ways to do this, though; you can get all the keys in an array, and just iterate through those rather than iterating through all possible keys: this sort of programming could quickly kill a web app if it has to search every number index before getting to an 'a' in the array.

Comment: @user2113060 you should go for Nathaniel Ford's solution, it's more efficient !

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV, ok thnx, I would go for that!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo $key."=>".$value; 
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: sorry, I mentioned in for loop.

Comment: ah sorry..why only a for loop and not a foreach though?

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to print in for loop?

Answer (score -1):

You want to start your loop with $i=0 as PHP uses zero indexing.  also in your loop you want to cap your max value for interation at $i

```
  <?php
    $array=array(0=>"hello",
                 1=>"world", 
                 2=>"this", 
                 3=>"is", 
                 4=>"an", 
                 20=>"array",
                 21=>"code" );

    $length=count($array);

    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
             echo "$i=>".$array[$i]; 
             echo "<br />";

          }
    ?>
```

Comment: but still it won't print index 20 and 21.

Comment: This code is non-functioning: you will get an array index out of bounds exception when it attempts to access '5', which does not exist in this array.

Comment: yeah that problem, Nathaniel, i want to print whole array without getting that.

Comment: Why has it to be a for loop? Foreach no possibility?

Comment: I have been asked particularly to use for loop.